# How create middleware group for route

Tags: php, middleware, slim-3

Is it possible to create middleware groups for each route in slim3? I create a route, in the `middleware.php` file I set a list of middlewares and it turns out all the routes will go through this list, but I don’t need it. And the second question is how do I get access to attributes in the middleware, outputting `$request->getAttribute('paramName')`, I get NULL?

Answer (score 0):

You say that you don't want all routes to match (I assume this is a case of application-wide middleware), but you don't elaborate on what kind of match *do* you want.

So I am not sure what do you mean by a *group* of middleware precisely. You can add middlewares to a specific routes or route groups.

Example of adding middleware to a route group from documentation:

```php
$app->group('/utils', function () use ($app) {
    $app->get('/date', function ($request, $response) {
        return $response->getBody()->write(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    });
    $app->get('/time', function ($request, $response) {
        return $response->getBody()->write(time());
    });
})->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
    $response->getBody()->write('It is now ');
    $response = $next($request, $response);
    $response->getBody()->write('. Enjoy!');

    return $response;
});
```

https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/concepts/middleware.html#group-middleware